# PHP equivalent of cURL "user-interface" for IMAP

Tags: php, curl, imap

I would like to know, if there is a way to choose what IP to use when sending an IMAP request ?

For example, i have a server with 4 ip adresses and i want to use the 2nd one for IMAP. I look for something, like the "user-interface" in cURL, which allows you to use one of your server IPs.

Comment: If your server has 4 IPs, but a given service is running on only only one of them, then you should have a hostname defined in DNS that points only to that address, eg `imap.example.com`. Choosing "the second one" in the application is wholly unreliable at best.

Comment: Do you mean binding of the client socket to an IP, not the server endpoint?

Comment: Thanks for you're answer,
I thinks i wasn't clear enough in my question sorry about that.
My imap connection always takes the first ip and i want to be able to change that ip as i want,
i'm not an expert with servers,
but isn't it possible to do so just with PHP ?

Comment: I found this soloution but i don't see how to use it to get the content of an email or how to 'mark it as seen'.
However it could help somone else so here it is
**curl --max-time 20 --ipv4 --interface 255.255.255.255 --user-agent "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)" "imaps://imap-mail.outlook.com:993/imap/ssl/" --cacert ".\cacert.pem" -u EmailLogin:EmailPassword -k**

Comment: i am interested. Where did you find this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer you were looking for, is, quite unsurprisingly, CURLOPT_INTERFACE.

From [documentation](http://php.net/curl_setopt):

**CURLOPT_INTERFACE**    The name of the outgoing network interface to use. This can be an interface name, an IP address or a host name.

Answer (score 0):

**Php**

```
$ch = curl_init();

      if($ch) {

        /* Set username and password */ 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "user");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "secret");

        /* This will fetch message 1 from the user's inbox */ 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "imap://imap.example.com/INBOX/;UID=1");

            $proxy = '127.0.0.1:8888';
            //$proxyauth = 'user:password';

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);


        /* Perform the fetch */ 
        $res = curl_exec($ch);

        /* Always cleanup */ 
        curl_close($ch);
      }
```

**Resources**

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/imap-fetch.html